# Did Hiromu Arakawa have any input on the 2003 FMA?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-2003

The 2003 Fullmetal Alchemist anime, as we all know, departed significantly plot-wise from the manga. The mangaka for FMA is Hiromu Arakawa. Did she have any input on the plot or production of the 2003 anime, or was it written by other people just based on the manga?

Answer (score 2):

It was directed by Seiji Mizushima, written by Shō Aikawa and co-produced by Bones, Mainichi Broadcasting System and Aniplex. Character designs by Yoshiyuki Itō. During the making of the anime, Arakawa was present in meetings to advise the staff about the world of Fullmetal Alchemist, though she did not write for the television series.

Source:[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fullmetal_Alchemist_(anime))

Comment: Did she contribute to the plot, though, or was she just providing details about the world in general?

Comment: During the development of Fullmetal Alchemist, Arakawa allowed Bones to work independently from her, and requested an original ending different from that of the original manga. She did not want to repeat the same ending in both media, and wanted to continue writing the manga to develop the characters.

In short, just the world and not the entire plot.